# Listing products with multiple categories in Prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm communicating with Prestashop 1.5 Web Services for listing products and its filters are simple enough for basic cases, but what about multiple categories:

1. Can I get a list of products that belong to category 1 AND 2?
2. Can I get a list of products that belong to category 1 OR 2?

Comment: Hi @xDaizu, I never got any answer from you on my post bellow. Do you need more clarification on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

For your information here is Prestashop 1.5 Filter management process in `classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest`:

```php
/**
 * get SQL retrieve Filter
 *
 * @param string $sqlId
 * @param string $filterValue
 * @param string $tableAlias = 'main.'
 * @return string
 */
protected function getSQLRetrieveFilter($sqlId, $filterValue, $tableAlias = 'main.')
{
    $ret = '';
    preg_match('/^(.*)\[(.*)\](.*)$/', $filterValue, $matches);
    if (count($matches) > 1)
    {
        if ($matches[1] == '%' || $matches[3] == '%')
            $ret .= ' AND '.bqSQL($tableAlias).'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'` LIKE "'.pSQL($matches[1].$matches[2].$matches[3])."\"\n";
        elseif ($matches[1] == '' && $matches[3] == '')
        {
            if (strpos($matches[2], '|') > 0)
            {
                $values = explode('|', $matches[2]);
                $ret .= ' AND (';
                $temp = '';
                foreach ($values as $value)
                    $temp .= bqSQL($tableAlias).'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'` = "'.bqSQL($value).'" OR ';
                $ret .= rtrim($temp, 'OR ').')'."\n";
            }
            elseif (preg_match('/^([\d\.:-\s]+),([\d\.:-\s]+)$/', $matches[2], $matches3))
            {
                unset($matches3[0]);
                if (count($matches3) > 0)
                {
                    sort($matches3);
                    $ret .= ' AND '.$tableAlias.'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'` BETWEEN "'.pSQL($matches3[0]).'" AND "'.pSQL($matches3[1])."\"\n";
                }
            }
            else
                $ret .= ' AND '.$tableAlias.'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'`="'.pSQL($matches[2]).'"'."\n";
        }
        elseif ($matches[1] == '>')
            $ret .= ' AND '.$tableAlias.'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'` > "'.pSQL($matches[2])."\"\n";
        elseif ($matches[1] == '<')
            $ret .= ' AND '.$tableAlias.'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'` < "'.pSQL($matches[2])."\"\n";
        elseif ($matches[1] == '!')
            $ret .= ' AND '.$tableAlias.'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'` != "'.pSQL($matches[2])."\"\n";
    }
    else
        $ret .= ' AND '.$tableAlias.'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'` '.(Validate::isFloat(pSQL($filterValue)) ? 'LIKE' : '=').' "'.pSQL($filterValue)."\"\n";
    return $ret;
}
```

From this we can notice that, unlike what the [official documention](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+8+-+Advanced+use#Chapter8-Advanceduse-RenderingFilters) says:

- We can simulate a `OR` condition with a pipe `|` between values.
- We can simulate a `BETWEEN` condition with a coma `,` between values.
- We can simulate a `LIKE %%` condition with a leading or/and a following percent `%` of our value.
- We can simulate a `>` condition with a `>` in front of the value.
- We can simulate a `<` condition with a `<` in front of the value.
- We can simulate a `!=` condition with a `!` in front of the value.

But I can't find a solution to simulate a `AND` condition. If you find one feel free to update this answer.

You can easily override this method to add your own `AND` filter.

---

For Prestashop 1.6 there's a little difference with the `!` condition:

```php
} elseif ($matches[1] == '!') {
     $multiple_values = explode('|', $matches[2]);
     foreach ($multiple_values as $value) {
         $ret .= ' AND '.$tableAlias.'`'.bqSQL($sqlId).'` != "'.pSQL($value)."\"\n";
     }
}
```

- We can simulate a `NOT IN()` by adding a pipe `|` between each values with a leading `!`.