# Prestashop special price for product

Tags: web-services, api, prestashop

how I can get all special_prices for a specific product id?

using this call: http://prestashop.test.com/api/specific_prices/?display=full 
it return me ALL SPECIAL PRICES of all products. How I can filter it by specific product_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Prestashop 1.6 API Documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Chapter+8+-+Advanced+use#Chapter8-Advanceduse-RenderingFilters):

```
http://prestashop.test.com/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[5]
```

With this request we will retrieve all `specific_prices` for the product with `id_product=5`.

---

For more informations see my other post [listing all API filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35581672/5659190)